# Finding an asymptotic expansion of $\log(1-\log(\epsilon))$

Tags: perturbation-theory

I have to find the asymptotic expansion of $\log(1-\log(\epsilon))$ for $\epsilon>0$.

My first thought was that I could use the expansion of $\log(1+x)$ but then I get $-\log(\epsilon)-\frac{\log(\epsilon)^2}{2}...$ so each term is increasing in size.

How do I go about finding the correct sequence to use?

Comment: If $\epsilon\to 0^+$ then $\log(\epsilon)\to -\infty$. The expansion of $\log(1+x)$ works when $x$ is infinitesimal!

Comment: Following up on @RobertZ's comment: when $\varepsilon$ is very close to $0$, there's asymptotically no difference between $\log(1-\log\varepsilon)$ and $\log|\log\varepsilon| = \log\log\frac1\varepsilon$. The second-order term added would be $(\log\log\frac1\varepsilon) \big/ (\log\frac1\varepsilon)$ if that's important.

Comment: $$
\log (1 - \log \varepsilon ) = \log (1 + \log (1/\varepsilon )) = \log \log (1/\varepsilon ) + \log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{\log (1/\varepsilon )}}} \right)\\ = \log \log (1/\varepsilon ) + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^{k + 1} }}{{k\log^k (1/\varepsilon )}}} 
$$ for $0 < \varepsilon \leq e^{ - 1} $.